# How to find p value for trend in a Proportional Hazards Cox regression model?

Tags: p-value, nonlinear-regression

I am running an analysis using a Proportional Hazards Cox regression models. My main interest variable is categorized and I find a significant effect only on medium category. I would like to see what's the p trend to examine the chance to have a linearity problem. How can I find this p value for trend across the categories?

Comment: In Cox regression, when interpreting categorical variables, you are always set to have one level as the reference, and all other levels of the variable are being compared to that reference. Checking for a trend is not (as far as I know) possible routinely in Cox regression. You could however check for a trend in your estimates. I.e appreciate whether estimates appear to display a trend; significance could hopefully be of inferior importance...

Comment: If your variable is continuous (i.e you have created categories from a continuous variable) I suggest you go back to the continuous version of the predictor and model it with splines to check for non-linearity.

Comment: Thank you Adam but I am using SPSS and splines are too advanced for me to know how to model them. Indeed my categories are coming from a continuous variable. Any other solution?

Comment: I'd actually try to fit it with a spline... You should get R. I didn't like it either. I used to use SPSS but now I understand R is almost just as simple. You could find a lot of great tutorials for R in no time. (I don't know how to fit splines in SPSS...)

Comment: Good example here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21964/different-prediction-plot-from-survival-coxph-and-rms-cph