# Different prediction plot from visreg versus ggplot(Predict())

Tags: data-visualization, predictive-models, cox-model

The problem:
I am hoping to visualise interaction effects between a continuous and a dichotomous variable from a cox proportional hazard regression. When graphing this with different packages (visreg and rms:ggplot(Predict()), I got bafflingly different looking graphs. What did I miss in these two approaches that generated this disagreement?

Also when I am plotting for hazard ratio (with fun=exp), I am not getting the reference point with the narrowed confidence band as suggested in this discussion ( [Different prediction plot from survival coxph and rms cph](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21964/different-prediction-plot-from-survival-coxph-and-rms-cph)) (what did I miss here?).

Example:

```
# Load libs
library(survival)
library(rms)
library(visreg)

# Regular survival
survobj <- with(lung, Surv(time,status))

# Prepare the variables
lung$sex <- factor(lung$sex, levels=1:2, labels=c("Male", "Female"))
label(lung$sex) <- "Sex"
label(lung$age)<- "Age"

# The rms survival
ddist <- datadist(lung)
options(datadist="ddist")
rms_surv_fit <- cph(survobj~rcs(age, 4)*sex, data=lung, x=T, y=T)
p <- Predict(rms_surv_fit, age=seq(50, 70, times=20), 
             sex=c("Male", "Female"), fun=exp)
ggplot(Predict(rms_surv_fit,  age , sex))
```

Gives this plot
[image: Gives this plot]

To plot the hazard ratio (where I am expecting a reference point)

```
ggplot(Predict(rms_surv_fit,  age , sex, fun=exp))
```

[image: Hazard ratio plot]

```
# visreg
coxph_fit <-coxph(survobj~rcs(age, 4)*sex, data=lung)
visreg(coxph_fit, 'age', by='sex', overlay=T, partial=F, band=T, ylim=c(-3, 3) )
```

Gives very different graphs compared to above two:

[image: which graphed the following (very different lines as well as confidence intervals]

I came across suggestions that the meaning of above conditional plot is likely questionable since baseline hazard is not estimated -  a contrast plot is herhaps more appropriate as graphed below:

[image: I came across suggestions that the meaning of above conditional plot is likely questionable since baseline hazard is not estimated; Thus a contrast plot is graphed as below:]

```
visreg(coxph_fit, 'age', by='sex', overlay=T, partial=F, type='contrast' )
```